css :not() pseudo class is not working i think


:not(article *) {
 color: orange;
}
<article>
  <h1>This is a heading</h1>
  <p>This is a paragraph.</p>
  <p>This is another paragraph.</p>
  <div>This is some text in a div element.</div>
  <a href="https://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>
</article>
<h2>test</h2>



I want to make the color of the elements that are not inside the article element orange, but it doesn't work.
This is my current output:


The question you've asked has been closed, but that's because what you've asked is not the answer to your problem. Just use * { color: orange; } to set all element colors, then article > * { color: initial; } to revert just for the children of the article elements. You don't always need to solve CSS problems in a single selector.
